# How do I add Shopware 6 Administration configuration from inside a Symfony bundle?

Tags: symfony, shopware, shopware6

I'm trying to add configuration to the administration area of Shopware 6 from inside a Symfony bundle.

I have followed the [official documentation](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/v/6.4/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-fundamentals/add-plugin-configuration), but nothing gets displayed in the administration area.

The bundle config resides under the path

```
MyBundle/Resources/config/config.xml
```

with the content from the documentation

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shopware/platform/trunk/src/Core/System/SystemConfig/Schema/config.xsd">
    <card>
        <title>Basic Configuration</title>
        <title lang="de-DE">Grundeinstellungen</title>
        <input-field>
            <name>email</name>
            <copyable>true</copyable>
            <label>eMail address</label>
            <label lang="de-DE">E-Mail Adresse</label>
            <placeholder>you@example.com</placeholder>
            <placeholder lang="de-DE">du@beispiel.de</placeholder>
            <helpText>Please fill in your personal eMail address</helpText>
            <helpText lang="de-DE">Bitte trage deine persönliche E-Mail Adresse ein</helpText>
        </input-field>
    </card>
</config>
```

Even after deleting the cache and rebuilding the administration via console commands, it does not show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: In your `MyBundle.php` make sure you extend `Shopware\Core\Framework\Bundle` instead of `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle`. This should enable most  capabilities of actual plugins, including the `config.xml` getting parsed. The exception would of course be the lifecycle events commonly associated with plugins like installation, activation, deinstallation etc via the extension manager.

```php
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Bundle;

class MyBundle extends Bundle
{
    protected $name = 'MyBundle';
}
```

This will however **not** make your bundle appear among regular plugins in the administration. **But** since the `config.xml` is being parsed you can access the page with the rendered fields directly via the corresponding URL:

```
http://localhost/admin#/sw/extension/config/MyBundle
```

So in theory you only need to extend the administration and place a link to that page somewhere, since your bundle is not listed as a plugin.

---

**Old answer (referring to using a plugin instead):**

This looks good. You refer to what you have as a Symfony bundle. While a plugin is an extension of a bundle, parsing the `config.xml` happens only with actual plugins.

Unless installed via composer the file should then be located at `custom/plugins/MyBundle/Resources/config/config.xml` or `custom/static-plugins/MyBundle/Resources/config/config.xml` and `MyBundle.php` should extend `Shopware\Core\Framework\Plugin`. The plugin must then be installed either by administration or via cli `bin/console plugin:install MyBundle --activate`

Comment: Thank you, but there are pre-existing bundle features stopping me from turning this into a plugin without a lot of effort. Is there another way to force the inclusion of the `config.xml`, for example, how the `address.xml` of the `System` bundle from `shopware/core` gets included in the `ConfigurationService->fetchConfiguration` function?

Comment: You normally find the configuration fields of a plugin via the extension manager in the administration. Even if you could get the system to read your `config.xml`, there would be no way to access the fields out of the box. You may persist and read config values via the `Shopware\Core\System\SystemConfig\SystemConfigService` service as you wish, however to get the corresponding fields to render you'll have to extend the administration manually, which also will be less trivial without the capabilities of a plugin. What are those pre-existing bundle features you speak of?

Comment: Nothing Symfony or Shopware 6 related, the project directory structure is different.

Comment: I updated my answer. You can actually get it to parse your `config.xml` and render the fields on a dedicated page, it's just a matter of navigating to that page at that point.